# Add space after commas only if it doesn't already?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to add a space after commas in a string only if it doesn't exist.

Example:

`word word,word,word,`

Would end up as

`word word, word, word,`

Is there a function in ruby or rails to do this?

This will be used on hundreds of thousands of sentences, so it needs to be fast (performance would matter).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using negative lookahead to check no space after comma, then replace with comma and space.

```
print 'word word,word,word,'.gsub(/,(?![ ])/, ', ')
```

Comment: This is the better solution, and it's significantly faster

Comment: @ArupRakshit `[ ]` means space. `(?![ ])` means not followed by space.  And `,(?![ ])` means a comma that is not followed by a space. So that we can replace the comma(without space) with comma + space.

Comment: Yeah. I could use only space without character class. But For easier understanding I used space inside `[]`.

Comment: tumi khub vlo *Regex* e... :)

Answer (score 4):

Just use a regular expression to replace all instances of `","` not followed by a space with `", "`.

```
str = "word word,word,word,"

str = str.gsub(/,([^ ])/, ', \1') # "word word, word, word,"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string contains no multiple adjacent spaces (or should not contain such), you don't need a regex:

```
"word word, word, word,".gsub(',', ', ').squeeze(' ')
  #=> "word word, word, word, "
```

Answer (score 0):

Add missing space:

```
 "word word,word,word,".gsub(/,(?=\w)/, ', ') # "word word, word, word,"
```

and removing the last unnecessary comma if necessary

```
"word word,word,word,".gsub(/,(?=\w)/, ', ').sub(/,\Z/, '') # "word word, word, word"
```